# How do I start my Rails Background Worker automatically in Production Environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I figured out that I start my background worker manually on Develoment Environment.

My payments/transactions will not get successful if my background worker is not running.

> **What I have done**
>
> I created a Procfile and inside it I have the following such that I
>   this below:

**ApplicationName/Procfile**

```
worker: bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

Will this actually solve my problem if I deploy my application? And if not, **how do I start background worker on Production?**

**Update**

I have been called to order from posted answers the Procfile works only for **Heroku**. Note that ***I like to deploy to DigitalOcean***. I am using Delayed_Job for my Background Worker, and inside its documentation, it states that we can use the following code on production with the help of bundling `"daemons" gem` with it.

```
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job stop
```

Is there anyway I can automate this by initilizing it, such that env. pick up the code to execute?

Answer (score 0):

Procfile will work only for heroku. So skip the rest of my answer if you are deploying to Heroku.

How to do it depends on system you are deploying. Most of the modern linux systems (i.e. Ubuntu) using systemd. So you very likely need to create startup script and put it to `/lib/systemd/system/__your_service__.service`

Just for example

```
[Unit]
Description=__Your worker_name__

[Service]
Type=forking
User=__your_user__
WorkingDirectory=__your_working_dir__
Environment=RAILS_ENV=production
PIDFile=__your_working_dir__/tmp/pids/__your_service__.pid
ExecStart=absolute_path_to_bundle exec rake jobs:work 

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And afterwards type and you are good :)

```
sudo systemctl enable __your_service__ && sudo systemctl start __your_service__
```

Comment: Am deploying to digital ocean. and I hope this works there. 

But what if I initialize it right in the config, will this this be visible?

Comment: @AfolabiOlaoluwaAkinwumi, but whom shall take care of your config? In the Heroku they have some special staff as they don't give you access on OS level but here you are the boss and should take care of your daemons. Btw, how do you run your app? Unicorn?

Comment: I never used Unicorn I run my app with: rails s